# CakePhp: How to know the current local in the model?

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, model

I've to develop a small website which is multi-lingual. This website is using an ERP database, so I cannot choose my database structure, ...

My application has the default language in the core.php, and I'm using [I18N Through URL](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization/) to specify which language I've to display

For every different language, I've a different table containing the description of products in the right language.

So I need to set the "$useTable" of cakePhp in the constructor to the right table. But to do this, I need to know the current locale of the application.

I tried several things:

- do a getInstance on the I18n class, but I've always "english" as "lang"
- doing a Configure::read('Config.language'), but this only displays me the default language of the cakePhp
- I tried to read the $GLOBALS['Dispatcher']->$params['language'] but if the user didn't specify any local, I don't get any
- I tried to import the Component Session and read the Config.language value(which I'm writing on the app_controller), but I seems that If I'm on a french page, I click on the link to display the page in german(all texts are in german now), but the value I receive here is still in french, if I refresh the page, I finally got German, but I need to get the value now, not on the next page reload

So I don't see how to retrieve this language, is there an hidden field containing this var, or anywhere I could retrieve this info?

Comment: Could you add your code of your AppController, and an example controller you're working with?

Comment: My controller is exactly the same than specified in my link. And I need to get the current locale in the model, not in the controller

Comment: You can specify the table in the controller: `$this->$model->useTable = 'rus';`, etc. Surely your controller AppController can't be exactly the same - you are writing a custom application, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found any easy way to retrieve this var, and because we are called before the _beforeFilter, I've to check parameter, session, cookies and default var.

So I created a method, I put it in my "Tools" component, and I import it in my model.

Here is the model if you're interessted:

```
function GetCurrentLocale(){
    if(isset($GLOBALS['Dispatcher']->params['language'])) return $GLOBALS['Dispatcher']->params['language'];
    if($this->Session->check('Config.language')) return $this->Session->read('Config.language');
    if($this->Cookie->read('lang')!==false)return $this->Cookie->read('lang');
    return Configure::read('Config.language');      
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
    App::import('component','Tools');
    $tools = new ToolsComponent();
    $locale = $tools->GetCurrentLocale();
```

If someone find a best way, I will be strongly interessted to see how :)

Comment: Behaviours are best to add to models: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1071/Behaviors